# JBPM_7.XX: How to change role name "admin" to other name?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, redhat-bpm

Currently, I am integrating JBPM with LDAP with following guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UpT92-GIxc.

I have done successfully. But, Our LDAP server already have role "admin" and I cannot add this role to my OU. So, How can i change configuration admin role to other name in jbpm?

Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

In the `jbpm.usergroup.callback.properties` file, you should configure the "binding" user:

```
ldap.bind.user=cn\=admin,dc\=jbpm,dc\=org
ldap.bind.pwd=admin
```

You could try any other one, different than admin.

Notice that if the LDAP server doesn’t allow anonymous binding, then `ldap.bind.user` and `ldap.bind.pwd` parameters are mandatory in this file.

In this blog post, you can find a sample for a basic LDAP configuration ("LDAP structure" chapter):
https://blog.kie.org/2021/02/migrating-jbpm-images-secured-by-ldap-to-elytron.html

Take into account to update jboss LdapExtLoginModule with the bindDN and password accordingly.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Muñoz,

My problem is I don't want to user role "admin" (Because It is used  in LDAP before). I would like to create new role (ex: admin_new) and this role is similar with admin.

Comment: @MingNguyen, you should  define a different dc in case of clashing: cn=admin,ou=Roles,dc=jbpm,dc=org